How to delete all occurrences of `Answer.*` and paste it to the end of a file
How to delete all occurrences of Answer.* from a file and paste it to the end of a file using vim. I can use commands like sed or any others.
1. Lorem ipsum? Answer: lorem
2. Lorem? Answer: ipsum

.....   

.....

250000. Dolour? Answer: amet

End of the file or new file both acceptable.
Paste answers line by line
1. Lorem ipsum?
2. Lorem? 

.....   

.....

250000. Dolour? 


1. Answer: lorem
2. Answer: ipsum

.....   

.....

250000. Answer: amet



Do you insist to do this with vim or some command line tools are accepted too?

Also can you provide some example of input and expected output?

Please show literally what you want the result to look like. That's much more useful than a description of what it should look like.

With perl instead of vim:
$ cat file
some Answer whatever
only Question here
Answer my question please? Answer: OK
some other Answer with another Answer within

$ perl -pi -e 's/Answer.*/print STDOUT "$&\n"; ""/e' file > otherfile

$ cat -e file
some $
only Question here$
$
some other $

$ cat otherfile
Answer whatever
Answer my question please? Answer: OK
Answer with another Answer within

You can adapt to pick from the last occurrence of Answer on a line with:
perl -pi -e 's/.*\KAnswer.*/print STDOUT "$&\n"; ""/e' file > otherfile


Got empty file for answer

@Justin, you mean you used the same input file, ran that same exact perl command and got an empty otherfile as result?

In the Vim editor, in two steps:

Place a mark at the current end of the file.
:$ k a

Explanation:  This creates a mark called a that we can use in commands to address that line later.

Copy all lines that contain Answer: to the last line and delete the question bit of the text (the text from the first . to the last ?):
:g/Answer:/ t $ | s/\..*?//

Explanation: This applies t $ ("copy/transfer to the end") to all lines matching the regular expression Answer:.  After transferring a line, it removes the question with a substitution.

Remove the answer from all lines from 1 down to and including the a mark:
:1,'a s/ Answer:.*/

Explanation: This uses the a mark to apply a substitution on all lines from line 1 to the a line.  The substitution removes the answer from those lines.



In vim, you can do:
:%s/Answer.*/\=execute('let @a .= submatch(0) . "\n"')

To replace the Answer... with nothing while at the same time append the deleted text followed by a newline to the a register.
Then you can paste that register to another file with "ap or :put a as usual.
